# Using Cell content as a parameter of a Function in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just Started working with SQL Server and I want to set one column of my table based on another column(automatically and both columns are in a same table). I've wrote a function like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FloorNameConvertor] 
(
    @Number int
)    
RETURNS nchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 
(       CASE 
            WHEN @Number/100=1 THEN 'x'
            WHEN @Number/100=2 THEN 'y'
            ELSE 'w'
        END 
)
END
```

and I use it in default value of my column properties. I have problem to send a value of the cell as a parameter ( I can't select one cell )?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use other column names in default constraints. You can work it around with `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger or use computed column (not persisted though).

Comment: Thanks for you Reply. would you give me any useful link or references. and is it impossible to select specific cell in SQL (instead of selecting all column)?

Comment: @MohammadYousefi: It's possible in different context : For instance, `create table .... (field1 int, field2 as  [dbo].[FloorNameConvertor] (field1))` - computed column. However, if you try it with `... field2 nchar(10) default [dbo].[FloorNameConvertor](field1)` you will get "The name "field1" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted." error. Links : example of computed columns in create table - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Instead of trigger - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx